# Python cx_freeze error

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, cx-freeze

Python version: 3.6
Latest versions of packages

Hello, i need help with my setup,
I have setup file but it doesn't work and i don't know why

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib

base = None

if sys.platform =="win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("python.py", base=base,)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "music-Client",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","matplotlib","Pygame"]}},
    version = "1",
    description = "hello",
    executables = executables
    )
```

and when i try to build it with cmd, this really long error come

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    executables = executables
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "E:\Python\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "E:\Python\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "E:\Python\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "E:\Python\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "E:\Python\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "E:\Python\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 616, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 342, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 659, in IncludePackage
    module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 311, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 417, in _LoadModule
    namespace)
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 486, in _LoadPackage
    self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 464, in _LoadModule
    self._RunHook("load", module.name, module)
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 537, in _RunHook
    method(self, *args)
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 615, in load_tkinter
    tclSourceDir = os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]
  File "E:\Projekty\venv\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'
```

I dont know how to fix this, can anyone help me?
I really need help, thanks for answers

Comment: in your program you may have to set `os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]` with full path to library tcl (it can be `fullpath/tcl.dll` or `fullpath/libtcl.dll`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the tkinter libraries.  This can be done easily with the `os.environ()` method.

It should look like this:

```
import os
os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"] = "<PathToPython>/Python36-32/tcl/tcl8.6"
os.environ["TK_LIBRARY"] = "<PathToPython>/Python36-32/tcl/tk8.6"
```

In your script it will probably look something like this:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os
os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"] = "<PathToPython>/Python36-32/tcl/tcl8.6"
os.environ["TK_LIBRARY"] = "<PathToPython>/Python36-32/tcl/tk8.6"

base = None

if sys.platform =="win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("python.py", base=base,)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "music-Client",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","matplotlib","Pygame"]}},
    version = "1",
    description = "hello",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Note that I removed the `import mathplotlib` because this is not needed in the setup script, dependencies are generally detected.

---

## If this is not enough:

Very often another error is returned.  This is the missing run-times error.  You can include run-times (as described in the documentation) using the `include_files` method.  We can include this statement in this line:

```
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","matplotlib","Pygame"]}},
```

Like this:

```
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","matplotlib","Pygame"], "include_files":["<PathToPython>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll", "<PathToPython>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll"]}},
```